# C program to find the number with most different digits

Tags: c, loops

The user puts n numbers from his keyboard and I should find, between them, the number with the most different digits.

Example:

Enter number: 12

Enter number: 123

Enter number: 5555

The number with the most different digits is 123 (3 different digits).

The problem is that I am not supposed to use vectors or arrays or something else.
I should use only loops and if clauses. I know how to find the number of digits in a given number but how am I supposed to compare all of them to find the number of different digits?

Comment: keep track of them as the user enters the numbers, and only keep one number which has the most digits

Comment: By using status bits within an `int`, unless that is considered to be an array (of bits). For example, for the `5` digit, if bit 5 has not yet been set, increment the digit count. Then set bit 5.

Comment: You don't need to compare all of them. You just need a variable that holds the one with the most digits. After you read each number, test if it has more digits than the previous maximum. If so, you replace the variable and use that when comparing the next one.

Comment: @SamIam doesn't that form a vector?

Comment: @Barmar i don't want the one with the most digits, I want the one with the most DIFFERENT digits, so i should compare the digits "inside" each number.

Comment: I understand that, I was just being brief in my description. Replace "digits" with "different digits" throughout my comment.

Comment: Combine the @Barmar comments with mine, and you have it. But you must write it.

Comment: For each input loop through 0..9 and check if that digit exist. Count the different digits. Keep only the max count and it's input. It is probably easier to store the number in a string to find if a digit exist.

Comment: @WeatherVane please see the edited example, because I think that  you are not getting what I want.

Comment: @Al.Ka I read what you want and I edited the exmaple that did not bear it out. (You said 121 has 3 different digits).

Comment: @WeatherVane sorry I corrected it.

Comment: @WeatherVane now it is correct

Comment: @Al.Ka  I think I misunderstood which part of the problem you were having trouble with

Comment: @SamIam I got the answer from Chris, thanks.

Comment: @Al.Ka what you mean, is you got someone to write the code for you.

Comment: ..and I downvoted him for it.

Comment: Yeah.. favourited this in my 'Abuse by homework vamp' bookmarks:(

Comment: @WeatherVane I found this problem in a textbook (i am a beginer) i and it was in a chapter about only loops. I  wanted someone to help me out but apperently questions are not very welcomed in this site and everyone wants to show off so  I was just happy to find someone to understand what i was looking for.

Comment: @Al.Ka both Barmar and I understood and bewteen us gave hints as to how to write it. I even understood your own examples better than you. So please stop the negging, thank you.

Comment: Well, if it was an example in a textbook, the author presumably intended YOU to write the code, build it, test it an debug it. Since you just posted the question on here, why bother with the textbook - it's wasted space on your shelf.

Comment: @MartinJames Do you guys do exercises from a book only for your homework?

Comment: @MartinJames I "just posted the question here????" I have been trying to do this for two days!

Comment: Perhaps you had better switch to "humanities".

Comment: @WeatherVane english isn't my first language, what does that mean ?

Comment: @WeatherVane you voted for this question to be put on hold as "too broad" ???
This is laughing material, and sad at the same time because if this is too broad your minds must be too ... closed.

Comment: @Al.Ka no, that was the majority reason. Mine was *"Questions seeking debugging help ('why isn't this code working?') must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers."* See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example]((http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). **This a is not a please-write-my-code site.**

Comment: @WeatherVane I know what this kind of site is because I participate in the physics and math section, but I also know that the greatest minds in those sections are leaving the site cuz somethings are just wrong.
Someone says with full confidence that this is homework, and majority vote as too broad for no apparent reason.

Comment: Help Center_ "too broad - if your question could be answered by an entire book" Yeah I think thats the case in here.

Comment: I am puzzled as to why a [Computer engineer](http://physics.stackexchange.com/users/68625/al-ka) with a deep interest in physics and maths should find this problem anything but trivial.

Comment: Well, to be fair, it was slightly interesting, but only because of the madcademic restraints on arrays, vectors etc.  Still, of next-to-no actual use to future SO users, (unless they get the same assignm... textbook).

Comment: @WeatherVane I am not a computer engineer, I just started computer engineering. I have been learning programming for just a few days now.

Comment: @MartinJames Voting for this question as too broad is just wrong, no matter the other reasons.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The easiest way is to iterate through each possible digit (0 through 9) and see if it is there.

Something like this to determine the unique digits in a number:

```
int FindNumberDigits(int number) {
    int uniqueDigits=0;
    for(int i=0;i<10;++i) {
        int numberTemp=number;
        while(numberTemp) {
             if(numberTemp%10 == i) {
                 ++uniqueDigits;
                 break;
             }
             numberTemp/=10;
        }
    }
    return uniqueDigits;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Finally someone understood what i was looking for.

Comment: Note: Fails with all negative numbers.  Corner case error: `FindNumberDigits(0)`.

Comment: And too complex, a nested loop is not required.